# Converter Box SD CARD

Tags: sd-card

Unable to use last 2 Gigabytes of Storage on my SD card at the same rate as previous video.

I have been using a converter box for recording to an SD CARD. The amount of video was reduced to only 40 minutes for 2 Gigabytes, instead of 7 Hours for 6 GB. What would cause the difference in recording bitrates?

Trying to record video to SD card and make video file size consistent with recording previous files. I changed channels and made sure Television Set picked up video without interference.